# Serve static file index.html by default

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I've got a very simple angular app project that needs to do nothing more than serve static files from `wwwroot`. Here is my `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) { }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

Whenever I launch the project with IIS Express or web I always have to navigate to `/index.html`. How do I make it so that I can just visit the root (`/`) and still get `index.html`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply change `app.UseStaticFiles();` to `app.UseFileServer();`

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) { }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseFileServer();
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You want to server default files and static files:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
{
    ...
    // Enable serving of static files from the wwwroot folder.
    application.UseStaticFiles();
    // Serve the default file, if present.
    application.UseDefaultFiles();
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `UseFileServer` method which does the same thing using a single line, rather than two.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
{
    ...
    application.UseFileServer();
    ...
}
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html) for more information.

Comment: You must do it in this order (`app.UseDefaultFiles` before `app.UseStaticFiles`). Otherwise use `app.UseFileServer`, which is just shorthand for the same thing.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow Thanks, now fixed. For future reference, you can actually just edit other peoples answers directly.