# ASP.NET 5 RC1 Empty project template - Cannot configure file server to serve index.html - connection refused

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I've a very similar scenario to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794681/serve-static-file-index-html-by-default), namely I want a static file server which serves an index.html as the base of my angular app.

However when I try to access the page, I get the "This webpage is not available" ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in Chrome.

I took a peek in fiddler, where the error is:

```
[Fiddler] The connection to 'localhost' failed. 
Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made 
because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3340
```

I did the following:

Created a new **Empty** ASP.NET 5 Template. 
Added an empty index.html to the `wwwroot` folder.
Added the following code to the `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    app.UseFileServer();
}
```

The project.json file contains the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-15978"
},
```

while the global.json is

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  }
}
```

The strange thing is that if I create an MVC project, then replace its complete `Startup.cs` code with the two lines above it works like a charm.

So the question is: what do I need to make this work when I'm using an Empty template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles` version to `1.0.0-rc1-final`. Your issue may be caused by exception because of package incompatibility.

Comment: Yeah, this solved the issue, thanks. I still cannot believe it was as simple as this :)