# Show alert error message when certain condition arises

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code on page load that I use to show an error alert:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["message"] == "noemployees")
                    AlertDanger.Visible = true;
```

---

This is where the error is called. The page reloads and the error is shown.

```
if (payFitments == null)
{
     Response.Redirect("Default?message=noemployees");
}
```

I have the following markup

```
 <script type="text/javascript">       
        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $(".alert").fadeTo(1500, 0).slideUp(500, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }, 3000);
        });
       -------------------------
<div runat="server" visible="false" id="AlertDanger" class="alert alert-danger">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>You must have at least one employee to process</strong>
    </div>
```

How do I show this message without having to load the default page again? Not seeing examples on the web that show this clearly.

Comment: Please add question clearly, In which scenario you want to show alert and what is your trouble? This is one way you are showing the alert. Please write requirement in more details

Comment: When payFitments  is null, I want to show the AlertDanger message in the div. However, I do now want the page to reload as other entered form values will be lost.

Comment: have you tried using thisPage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true);

Comment: call javascript function from c# method then it will work

Comment: Yes I have tried this option. Problem is it is a pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `JQuery` `remove`, which effectively deletes the alert from your DOM. So showing it again without reloading your page is not possible.

But you could use `JQuery` `detach` instead. Then you can insert it again with `appendTo`.

```js
var alert = null;

function showHideAlert() {
    if (alert) {
        alert.appendTo("body");
        alert = null;
    } else {
        alert = $(".alert").detach();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button onclick="showHideAlert();">Show/Hide alert</button>
    <div class="alert">ALERT!!!</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try serving a static html file and then using the alert function in Javascript. You can learn that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794681/serve-static-file-index-html-by-default). Example for a button press:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function onError() {
      try {
        ...
      } catch (...) {

        var error
        error = "button was pressed"
        alert(error)
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="myButton" onClick="onError()">do not click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" /><%--  Also Check  Compatible View --%>

    <%-- Put all your jQuery... Here I'm showing an example--%>
    <script src="//ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $(".alert").fadeTo(1500, 0).slideUp(500, function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }, 3000);
        });

    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <div runat="server" visible="false" id="AlertDanger" class="alert alert-danger">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a> <strong>You must have at
            least one employee to process</strong>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note:- I think you have missed this... put your jQuery code inside your body tag...

Comment: *I think you have missed*, or you can ask if OP is facing error of `$` is not defined.

Comment: The code is working. Only that I do not want to have to reload and refresh page to show and show the alert. I am using RegisterStartupScript for now.